# Pass function-style macro as argument to another function-style macro

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to pass the name of a function-style macro as an argument to another function-style macro like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define FOO(x, y) (x+y) 

#define CALL_MACRO(macro, ...) macro(__va_args__)

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", CALL_MACRO(FOO, 2, 3)); 
    return 0; 
}
```

but I get these errors:

```
tests.c:8:40: error: macro "FOO" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
    8 |     printf("%d\n", CALL_MACRO(FOO, 2, 3));
      |                                        ^
tests.c:3: note: macro "FOO" defined here
    3 | #define FOO(x, y) (x+y)
      |
tests.c:8:31: error: ‘FOO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    8 |     printf("%d\n", CALL_MACRO(FOO, 2, 3));
      |                               ^~~
tests.c:5:32: note: in definition of macro ‘CALL_MACRO’
    5 | #define CALL_MACRO(macro, ...) macro(__va_args__)
      |                                ^~~~~
tests.c:8:31: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
    8 |     printf("%d\n", CALL_MACRO(FOO, 2, 3));
      |                               ^~~
tests.c:5:32: note: in definition of macro ‘CALL_MACRO’
    5 | #define CALL_MACRO(macro, ...) macro(__va_args__)
      |
```

Comment: @P__J__ OP's only problem is the typo: `__va_args__` instead of `__VA_ARGS__`. The code works if you fix that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat wow that fixed it. Thanks.